# Kali linux doesn't recognize my WN722N usb adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, network-adapter, kali-linux, adapter

Today I installed kali linux on a usb (with persistence) , everything went smoothly, but the only problem is that kali doesn't recognize my usb wifi adapter. The weird thing is that I have a kali dual boot in the same computer that recognizes my wi-fi card just fine! Any ideas what the problem is? iwconfig prints:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

In both installations I used the same ISO. In both of them I run apt-get update/upgrade. Any help is appreciated but take into consideration that Im really new to kali and linux in general.

**Edit:** I'm adding a part of the dmesg log in case it helps:

```
[ 1224.388951] usb 5-5: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1225.958821] usb 5-5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 1226.107718] usb 5-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
[ 1226.107726] usb 5-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[ 1226.107731] usb 5-5: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
[ 1226.107735] usb 5-5: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
[ 1226.107739] usb 5-5: SerialNumber: 12345
[ 1227.122503] SQUASHFS error: xz decompression failed, data probably corrupt
[ 1227.122511] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x522baac
[ 1227.122516] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache entry [522baac]
[ 1227.122520] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 522baac, size 5ef0
```

Comment: What is the reply to `modprobe ath9k_htc`?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath9k_htc': Input/output error`

Comment: There you go: you cannot load the driver. Search for `ath9k_htc` in the output of `dmesg`, and you will know more. It **may** be because of the SQUASHFS error.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: The system (udev) probably tried to load the kernel module automatically and failed. The module insertion failure apparently wasn't reported by udev and therefore doesn't appear in `dmesg`, but the resulting I/O error certainly was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The compressed system image is corrupt.

```
SQUASHFS error: xz decompression failed, data probably corrupt
```

- The system was unable to decode the part of the compressed system image on which the kernel module resides. As a result, `modprobe` fails with an I/O error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath9k_htc': Input/output error
```

- It's possible that your flash drive has bad sectors, so you might want to try installing Kali on another flash drive. If the problem persists, you might want to test your system's memory using a program such as [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) as faulty memory can cause the resulting image on the flash drive to become corrupt.
- If your system's memory is okay and installing onto a different drive didn't help, then you may have run into a bug in Kali itself.

Comment: I installed it on another flash drive and it worked! Thanks for the help!